# How do I count all the items that are the same in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, json, count

I have a List of countries:

```
Ghana
Kenya
Thailand
India
Cameroon
Tanzania
Kenya
Cameroon
India
Uganda
Argentina
Kenya
Uganda
```

I'm using a `foreach()` to display the countries:

```
 $json = file_get_contents('PATH_TO_JSON');
 $obj = json_decode($json, true);

 foreach($obj as $project_info){
          $list = $project_info['country'];    
}
```

My question is how do I display a count of all countries that are the same?

Example:

```
 Kenya(3)
 India(2)
 ... and so on
```

I played around with `array_count_values()` but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You should post the JSON and not the raw values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the `country` values from each sub-array and then count them:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$countries_count = array_count_values(array_column($array, 'country'));

foreach($countries_count as $country => $count) {
    echo "$country ($count)";
}
```

I used `$array` instead of `$obj` because it's an array not an object.

Comment: Thank you sir, Works perfect!!